# Add android-numberpicker backport to Android Studio Gradle project

Tags: android

I want to use this library in my Android Studio project https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker. I can't for the life of me figure out how to add it to my project. Can someone just outline how this would work? I've only ever added libraries that were contained in jar files.

Comment: Did you figure this out.  The answer below doesn't work as the file is contained in a apklib which isn't supported when i try and add it

Comment: I believe I just ended up adding the source as a library rather than using gradle.

Comment: Yeah i figured something out after i posted.  I imported the library as its own module in Android Studio and then imported the aar files into the solution.  Got there in the end.

Comment: @Modika Hey, I really getting stuck. I tried to add this library more to android studio but it still give me apklib. Could you please give me the steps to integrate it to my application asap. Thanks!

Comment: @heema, honestly i cant really remember as i dont do android stuff in the main. I remember something about creating some form of module from the source in android studio and then importing it but really cant remember the steps fully

Comment: @Modika Thanks so much for your reply. It's still not working but I will do some tries hope it work.

Comment: @heema i think i did this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16634680/228884

Comment: @Modika Thanks for your help. I tried but it doesn't work for sorry!

Answer (score 1):

In build.gradle, use:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'net.simonvt', name: 'android-numberpicker-parent', version: '1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using new gradle build system (and you really should), just add

```
compile 'net.simonvt:android-numberpicker:1.0.0'
```

to your build.gradle's dependencies section.

Answer (score 0):

I found a forked version of this library which can be imported from source as a module in Android Studio. It is available here:
https://github.com/heavyplayer/android-numberpicker